Type 'FormGroup<{ name: FormControl<string | null>; }>' is not assignable to type 'FormGroup<IForm>'. Types of property 'controls' are incompatible
I am working on Angular 14, Typescript 4.7, Angualr/forms: 14.3.0.
Below is a minimum error reproducible code snippet.
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, FormControl, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-learn',
  templateUrl: './learn.component.html',
})
export class LearnComponent {

  constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder) { }

  public form!: FormGroup<IForm>

  private buildForm(): FormGroup<IForm> {
    const form: FormGroup<IForm> = this.formBuilder.group({
      name: new FormControl<string>("Sample Name", Validators.required),
    });
    return form as FormGroup<IForm>;
  }

  private createContractModel(): IData {
    const formValues = this.form.value;
    const contract: IData = {
      name: formValues.name as string,
    }
    return contract;
  }
}

interface IForm {
  name: FormControl<string>;
}

interface IData {
  name: string;
}

I am getting the following error:
Type 'FormGroup<{ name: FormControl<string | null>; }>' is not assignable to type 'FormGroup<IForm>'.
Types of property 'controls' are incompatible.
Type '{ name: FormControl<string | null>; }' is not assignable to type 'IForm'. ts(2322)

Error (TS2322) 
    FormGroup<{ name: FormControl<string | null> }>' is not assignable to type FormGroup<IForm>. 
    Types of property controls are incompatible.
        Type '{ name: FormControl<string | null> }' is not assignable to type IForm.


And TypeScript also requires me to have type assertion as string, in the code.
How can I resolve the error and not use the type assertion.

The form control, is of type string | null, so you should set the interface, so accept both string | null.
interface IForm {
  name: FormControl<string | null>;
}

Stackblitz Demo

If you are 100% certain, that the form control is not nullable and will always contain a string, then you can use `` to make sure the value is not null.
private buildForm(): FormGroup<IForm> {
  const form: FormGroup<IForm> = this.formBuilder.group({
    name: this.formBuilder.nonNullable.control('Sample Name', Validators.required),
  });
  return form as FormGroup<IForm>;
}

Stackblitz Demo
